# Are events blocking or non-blocking when you call them?

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, blocking

Let's say I have an event `Tick` which I call:

```
public class Test
{
    public event Action Tick;

    public void Test()
    {
         Tick();
         Console.WriteLine("Tick Finished");
    }
}
```

If I have loads of events subscribed to `Tick`, will the operation of this thread that is running `Test()` be blocked until they have all been called or does it perform this asynchronously?

Comment: Similar question to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049844/are-public-events-asynchronous-do-they-execute-on-a-separate-thread

Comment: Events are blocking (meaning that they run *synchronously* with the thread that calls them). But they're just delegates, so you can use `BeginInvoke` to make them asynchronous. See more information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301332.aspx).

Comment: @Cody Gray: Thanks, and just to clarify for others - in this case I want events to be blocking.

Comment: So, where is your EventHandler?  You know, doing things like this runs afowl of standard practices and will make people maintaining your code hate you.

Comment: Also, we [should stop worrying and love dupes.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/)

Comment: @Will: My EventHandler is `System.Action` which is the same (but more descriptive imo) as writing `public delegate void MyEventHandler();`.

Comment: @CallumRogers: You are completely and utterly incorrect.  An event handler has the signature `(object sender, T e)` where `T : EventArgs`.  An `Action` takes no arguments whatsoever.  This is one of those places where there are no restraints on what you can do, other than the commonly accepted pattern of what you *should* do.  Another example is that you can `throw` any object, but it is considered bad practice to `throw` anything that does not extend `Exception`.  You may *think* using an Action as an event handler is "more descriptive" but doing so is very VERY bad practice.

Comment: @Will, in this case it really is unnecessary; the objects with the methods the event calls will always know the object that the has fired the event. It is worth noting that this is part of an experiment that could be seen as a "abuse" of events and C# in general - this is not just the standard UI with events usecase and is no way ever going to be used in the wild. However, for regular usecases of events, I agree with you entirely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All events are blocking. The thread execution will be blocked until all the event handlers registered to this event have been executed.

Comment: @Eurgene I am curious, what happen if you receive 3 events will it handle them all until its finished ?

Comment: @Rushino look for multicastdelegate

Answer (score 1):

While Tick() runs, it will block you from progressing further through the code.

To prove it to yourself, write a console app to do just that, that has a bunch of subscribers to the event, and watch to see what happens.